Getting aggregation response as number for string typed values in ElasticSearch
I ingested the payload into ES using below command.
 curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/demo3/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ 
  "longInt": 87366795768497144035, 
  "longStr":    "87366795768497144035",
}'

Here I ingested the longStr as string in payload and it will be registered long type in ES. When I am doing a composite aggregation in for the field, I am getting the result in number instead of string.
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/demo3/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[]}},"aggs":{"my_buckets":{"composite":{"sources":[{"Value":{"terms":{"field":"longStr"}}}]}}}}
'

I am here expecting to get the result in string, also I have noticed that it is getting a loose precision when doing aggregation for big values..

What's you version of es ? Numeric value (87366795768497144035) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)
